# Crystal Reports: Converting Selected Row Data to Column Data

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to transpose data for a select column in Crystal?  Here is my issue... I am using ttx file to get data fields for the Crystal Report...

I want only the tax_type and the tax_rate and tax amount  to show up in the same row as the product sold.  The tax_rate is stored in a separate table that needs to be pulled in as a column as well.  I need to group and sum on product, buy, sell,  tax_type, and then net the whole amount to come up with net total which I kinda know how... but I am stuck at transposing a row.  Basically I only want to show row as column where tax type, amount, and rate matches transaction number and YN_tax == 1.   The tax rate is stored in a totally separate table... Mind you that tax will not be applicable to each transaction... Here are the table Details

**Details Table**

```
    Transaction Sales_Date buy_sell  Product location  ProductType    price  amount  YN_tax  tax_type
    123456       11/9/2014  Sell    DEF      Brazil      trinkets     5     703.08

    123457       11/9/2014  Sell    ABC      Canada      widget       10    213.5

    123458       11/9/2014  Buy     DEF      Brazil      trinkets     2     630

    123459       11/9/2014  Buy     DEF      Brazil      trinkets     3     34.41

    123457       11/9/2014  Sell    ABC      Canada      SalesTax     3     688.2   1      SalesTax
    123458       11/9/2014  Buy     DEF      Brazil      FederalTax   2     132     1      FedTax
```

**Tax Rates Table**

```
    title           rate
    SalesTax        8.25
    FedTax          9.75
```

Comment: did you try linking your tables by tax_type = title? so in that way you can add Rate as column and it will show that rate whenever you have tax_type.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that... but the real issue is collapsing the two or more of tax rows into columns to show the tax total, the tax types as columns rather than rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it follow below process.

Before proceeding link the table so that you get `title` and `rate`.

1. Create a formula for every column as you want in the report and write formula as below.

   ```
      if YN_tax =1
    then tax_type
   ```

Above formula is for column `tax_type` in the similar way create individual formulas for all columns.